# Computationally random bitstreams and normalcy

Tags: nt.number-theory, pr.probability, measure-theory, computability-theory, computer-science

Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of non-negative integers. We can identify every bitstream, i.e. a function $s:\mathbb{N}\to \{0,1\}$, with some $A\in{\cal P}(\mathbb{N})$: take $A = s^{-1}(\{1\})$.

Given any $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ we define maps $\mu_S^+, \mu_S^-:{\cal P}(\mathbb{N})\to[0,1]$ by setting, for every $A\in{\cal P}(\mathbb{N})$, $$\mu^{+}_S(A)= \lim \sup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap S \cap\{1,\ldots,n\}|}{1+|S\cap \{1,\ldots,n\}|}, \text{ and } \mu^{-}_S(A)= \lim \inf_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap S \cap\{1,\ldots,n\}|}{1+|S\cap \{1,\ldots,n\}|}.$$

We say that $A$ is *well-balanced* with respect to $S$ if $\mu^+_S(A) = \mu^-_S(A) = 1/2$.

We say that $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is *computationally random* if for every [computable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_set) set $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, the set $A$ is well-balanced with respect to $S$. Morevover, we say that the bitstream $s:\mathbb{N}\to\{0,1\}$ is computationally random if $s^{-1}(\{1\})$ is computationally random.

Note that neither the [Thue-Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) or the [Champernowne sequence $C_2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant) are computationally random.

**Question.** Is every computationally random bitstream normal (that is, every finite $01$-string appears infinitely often)?

Comment: The linked article has a variety of definitions for algorithmic randomness, focusing on Martin-Lof randomness. Which one of those do you think might be identical with yours?

Comment: Your randomness notion is Church stochasticity, which is distinct from each of the randomness notions on the wikipedia page.

Comment: Thanks @DanTuretsky , I will check out Church stochasticity. I will change the question to make it more precise.

Comment: You need to be more clear on your definition of "normal". I think you mean to say normal in base 2, meaning that for every length $l$, every finite binary string of length $l$ appears with asymptotic density $\frac{1}{2^l}$, not just infinitely often.

Comment: You want to restrict $S$ to be infinite.  It's obviously not true if $S = A \cap \{1,\ldots,N\}$ for some $N$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $s$ be a computationally random bitstring.  Consider $\tilde{s}$
defined by $\tilde{s}(2n) = \tilde{s}(2n+1) = s(n)$. Then $\tilde{s}$ should also be computationally random, but it does not contain any $010$ or $101$.

Comment: Very slick argument -- thanks!