# Cardinals realizable by the chromatic number of a regular hypergraph

Tags: co.combinatorics, set-theory, graph-colorings, infinite-combinatorics, hypergraph

For any set $X$ and cardinal $\kappa$, we denote by $[X]^\kappa$ the collection of subsets of $X$ having cardinality $\kappa$.

If $H=(V,E)$ is a [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph), and $\kappa$ is a cardinal, we say that a map $c:V\to \kappa$ is a *coloring* if for every $e\in E$ with $|e|\geq 2$ the restriction $c|_e$ is non-constant. By $\chi(H)$ we denote the minimum cardinal such that there is a coloring $c:V\to \kappa$.

Let cardinals $\kappa\geq \omega$ and $\alpha,\beta$ with $2< \alpha, \beta \leq \kappa$ be given.

Is there necessarily $E \subseteq [\kappa]^\beta$ such that $\chi(\kappa,E) = \alpha$?  (There is an easy positive answer for either $\alpha$ or $\beta$ equal to $2$.)

Comment: Could you confirm that you mean non-constant rather than injective? For example, if I have a 3-edge with {a,b,c}, then I can color both a and c red, and b blue?

Comment: That's correct @JoelDavidHamkins. The starting point of my question was my [surprise](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349123/are-hypergraphs-h-v-e-with-e-v-2-colorable) that whenever $E\subseteq [\omega]^\omega$ is countable, then [$\chi(\omega, E) = 2$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349123/are-hypergraphs-h-v-e-with-e-v-2-colorable).

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins it is standard terminology in the hypergraph colorings theory

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thanks very much.

Comment: "Injective on edges" is the wrong generalisation of proper colouring to hypergraphs because it reduces to graph colouring by replacing hyperedges by graph cliques, whereas "non-constant" is more expressive.

Comment: For $\kappa=\beta=\aleph_\omega$, no subgraph of $[\kappa]^\beta$ has chromatic number greater than $\omega$, since we can color $\gamma\in\kappa$ with $n$ if $\aleph_{n-1}\leq\gamma<\alpha_n$, taking $\alpha_{-1}=0$ for convenience. I suspect the answer might be positive whenever $\alpha\leq cf(\kappa)$.

Comment: Thanks @Wojowu for your input on the cofinality! And a positive answer for $\alpha\leq cf(\kappa)$ would be fantastic!