# Set "crossing" all arithmetical integer sets

Tags: infinite-combinatorics

We say a set $A\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$ is *arithmetical* if there are integers $a>0,b\geq 0$ such that $A=\{ax+b:x\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

Is there $S\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$ such that $$S\cap A\neq\varnothing \neq (\mathbb{Z}\setminus S)\cap A$$
for every arithmetical set $A\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Enumerate all arithmetic sets $A_1, A_2, \ldots$. Choose $n_k\in A_k$ with $|n_k|>2^k$. The set $\{n_1, n_2, \ldots\}$ intersects any arithmetic set by construction, but it has zero density, thus does not contain a whole arithmetic set.

Actually you may construct such $S$ for each infinite sequence $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ of infinite sets: on $k$-th step choose $n_k\in A_k\cap S$ and $m_k\in A_k\setminus S$ so that $n_1, m_1, n_2, m_2, \ldots$ remain distinct.

Comment: If $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal number, and if $H$ is a hypergraph with at most $\kappa$ edges, and each edge contains at least $\kappa$ vertices, then $H$ is $2$-colorable. I'm surprised this hasn't come up yet, among all these questions about chromatic numbers of hypergraphs.

Comment: @bof Not quite the statement you mention, but another question which exactly answers this problem [has already been asked](https://mathoverflow.net/q/349123/30186).

Answer (score 7):

Another construction that works is to take any set $S$ such that both $S$ and $\mathbb Z\setminus S$ contain intervals of arbitrary length.

Comment: A simple example would be to let $S$ be the set of all positive integers.