# A sequence of cardinal characteristics constructed with hypergraph coloring

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, graph-colorings, hypergraph, cardinal-characteristics

Let $[\omega]^\omega$ denote the collection of infinite subsets of $\omega$.

A hypergraph $H=(V,E)$ consists of a set $V$ and a collection of subsets $E \subseteq {\cal P}(V)$. A *coloring* is a map $c: V\to \kappa$, where $\kappa \neq \emptyset$ is a cardinal, such that for every $e\in E$ with $|e|\geq 2$ the restriction $c|_e$ is non-constant. We denote the minimal cardinal $\kappa$ such that there is a coloring $c: V\to \kappa$ by $\chi(H)$ and call it the *chromatic number* of $H$

If $A\subseteq [\omega]^\omega$ is finite or countable, then [the chromatic number of $(\omega, A)$ equals $2$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349123/are-hypergraphs-h-v-e-with-e-v-2-colorable). This motivates the following cardinals: for any integer $n\geq 2$ let ${\bf k}_n$ be the minimum cardinality of a set $A\subseteq [\omega]^\omega$ such that $\chi(\omega, A) > n$.

Is it consistent in ${\sf ZFC}$ that $${\bf k}_n < {\bf k}_{n+1} < 2^{\aleph_0}$$
for all integers $n\geq 2$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cardinals $\bf k_n$ ($2\le n\lt\omega$) are all equal.

**Lemma.** Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal. Given a set $A\subseteq[\omega]^\omega$ with $|A|=\kappa$ and $\chi(\omega,A)\gt n$, we can construct a set $B\subseteq[\omega]^\omega$ with $|B|=\kappa$ and $\chi(\omega,B)\gt n^2$.

**Proof.** For each $a\in A$ choose a collection $B_a\subseteq[a]^\omega$ so that the hypergraph $(a,B_a)$ is isomorphic to $(\omega,A)$, and let $B=\bigcup_{a\in A}B_a$.

Let $(\omega,B)$ be colored with $n^2$ colors; let $[n]\times[n]$ be the set of colors, and let $x\mapsto(f(x),g(x))$ be the coloring. Since $\chi(\omega,A)\gt n$, there is a set $a\in A$ such that $f$ is constant on $a$. Then, since $\chi(a,B_a)\gt n$, there is a set $b\in B_a$ such that $g$ is constant on $b$.

**Corollary.** If there is a set $A\subseteq[\omega]^\omega$ with $|A|=\kappa$ and $\chi(\omega,A)\gt2$, then there is a set $B\subseteq[\omega]^\omega$ with $|B|=\kappa$ and $\chi(\omega,B)=\aleph_0$.

Comment: Wonderful @bof - and happy new year! - Do you happen to know whether ${\bf k}_2 < 2^{\aleph_0}$ is consistent?

Comment: I was wondering whether ${\bf k}_2 \in \{{\frak r}, {\frak s}\}$, denoting the reaping and splitting numbers respectively, could be proved, but I haven't had time to check this.

Comment: $\mathbf k_2=\mathfrak r$. The only difference between the definitions is that the former is about splitting into two nonempty sets where the latter is about splitting into two infinite sets. But that doesn't affect the cardinality because you can adjoin to any hypergraph $A$ all those sets that differ only finitely from members of $A$, and this won't increase the cardinality of $A$.

Comment: Thank you @AndreasBlass - and happy new year.