# A balancing property of infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, measure-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Let $\omega$ denote the set of non-negative integers and let $[\omega]^\omega$ be the collection of infinite subsets of $\omega$.

If $S\in [\omega]^\omega$ and $A\subseteq \omega$ we say that $A$ is *well-balanced with respect to* $S$ if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap S\cap \{1,\ldots,n\}|}{|S\cap\{1,\ldots,n\}|+1} = 1/2.$$ Intuitively speaking, this means that $A$ contains "half of the members of $S$" (which also implies that $A$ is infinite.)

**Question.** Given ${\frak S}\subseteq [\omega]^\omega$ with $|{\frak S}| = \aleph_0$, is there $A\in[\omega]^\omega$ such that $A$ is well-balanced with respect to every member of ${\frak S}$?

Comment: If we take ${\frak S}$ to be the collection of infinite [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_set) sets of $\omega$, then any such $A$ would correspond to a bitstream that is [computationally random](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335181/computationally-random-bitstreams-and-normalcy).

Comment: $\liminf a_n=\limsup a_n=1/2$ can be abbreviated as $\lim a_n=1/2$.

Comment: Oh right :-)  Will simplify the post accordingly, thanks @GHfromMO

Comment: A random subset of $\omega$ (meaning that $n\in A$ iff the $n^{\text{th}}$ toss in an infinite sequence of fair coin tosses comes of heads) will do the job with probability $1$.

Comment: Isn't this sometimes called [relative density](https://oeis.org/wiki/Density#Relative_density) (of the set $A$ with respect to the set $S$)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the strong law of large numbers, if $S$ is an infinite subset of $\omega$, a random subset of $\omega$ will be well-balanced with respect to $S$ with probability one.

By the countable additivity of Lebesgue measure, if $\mathfrak S$ is a countable collection of infinite subsets of $\omega$, a random subset of $\omega$ will be well-balanced with respect to every member of $\mathfrak S$ with probability one.

If Lebesgue measure is $\kappa$-additive (the union of fewer than $\kappa$ measure zero sets has measure zero) then the same holds for a collection $\mathfrak S$ of infinite subsets of $\omega$ with $|\mathfrak S|\lt\kappa$.